# Float Conversion Issue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, floating-point

I have an issue after converted a float from a string, the result of my operation is null

The NSLogs give the right value but vitesseMoyenne is equal to null

```
-(void)setVitesseMoyenne:(float)uneDistanceTotale:(NSString*)unTempsTotal
{
    //float tempEnFloat = [unTempsTotal floatValue];

    NSLog(@"%@",unTempsTotal);


    float calculVitesseMoyenne = uneDistanceTotale / [unTempsTotal floatValue];

    NSLog(@"%f",calculVitesseMoyenne);

    vitesseMoyenne =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", calculVitesseMoyenne];
}
```

Can you see what is wrong ?

Comment: WHere did your vitesseMoyenne variable is defined?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that vitesseMoyenne is a NSString

Unless you are using ARC the problem is that you are not retaining the NSString and so it gets autoreleased. *This does mean the reult is not always nil.

Try

```
 vitesseMoyenne =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", calculVitesseMoyenne]retain];
```

and release it when your class is released.